# How to ask a good (Western comics) story-ID question

Tags: discussion, story-identification, comics

*Copied from [Valorum's guide's question on video game identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11995/102999)*.

---

We seem to have a pretty regular number of story-ID questions specifically focused on finding half-remembered Western [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics).

Our top tag is [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) (with over 10,000 questions) and we already have an excellent guide to help people answer them in "[How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/102999)" that users can direct querents towards.

**What additional advice can we offer on writing a good story-identification question aimed at locating a specific Western comic book or graphic novel?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional information that would be useful when identifying Western comics questions includes;

- **How was it released?**

This is a really big one, as it can totally change the possible works it could be. Are you looking for an arc of a larger comic book series, a single issue, a graphic novel originally published in that format, or something else entirely? If it were a stand-alone graphic novel, I'd look in very different places from if it were a DC series.

- **Where was it released?**

Where did you read it? Give countries, and be more specific if it seems relevant (e.g. they might have different comics for sale in Quebec than other parts of Canada).

- **What did the cover look like?**

Try to describe the cover for us. What color was it? Who was on it? What sort of pose were they making?

- **Do you remember any specific dialogue or lines?**

Are there any phrases you specifically remember? These are good for finding these, as we can look for them in potential matches to check if they’re likely right.

- **What language was it in? What do you believe it was originally in?**

If, for example, it was in Inuktun, [which only has 800 speakers or so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Greenland) and apparently was originally in that language, that would be very useful to know and narrow it down a lot. It also can change how we'll look; Jenayah mentions using Portuguese and Spanish keywords to find answers in [a post describing how she finds answers to story identifications.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12294/102999)

- **Do you know who published it?**

Was it DC? Was it Marvel? If it was either, that eliminates a whole giant group of comics it could be misidentified as. If it was a smaller publisher and you know it, that narrows it down tons.

- **What genre was it?**

Was it a superhero comic? Was it comedic?

- **Who was it aimed at?**

Was it for kids? Was it very adult? If it was Marvel or DC and it was very violent and/or sexual, that's useful to know as it very much limits the years it could be from due to the Comics Code Authority's censorship.

- **What did the characters look like?**

What did the characters look like? Describe their clothes, faces, skin color, etc.

- **What style was it?**

What did it look like? Was it similar to Franco-Belgian [ligne claire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne_claire) comics like *TintinU? Did it look like [a 1960s DC comic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpMgt.jpg)? Did it look like [modern, computer-edited superhero comics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXHk.jpg)?

- **Can you remember anything else about the comic?**

Anything else? Was the author female? Because unfortunately so few DC and Marvel comic book writers/illustrators are women, this can narrow it down a lot.

Comment: Any panels they can supply are invaluable since those can be image-searched

Comment: @Valorum What do you mean? Descriptions of panels?

Comment: Yes, or actual scans of panels they've seen

Comment: @Stormblessed:
It's not uncommon for people to find the panels via memes (https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/Batman-Slapping-Robin) or out-of-context panels (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172484/what-is-the-context-for-this-panel-of-captain-marvelshazam-and-a-vibrating-mec). Sometimes, a reverse-image search will get it and sometimes not.

Comment: Anything else I can add?